# My subscribe method is called even before my greenrobot bus posts an event

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus

I'm trying to post an event from within a subscriber

```
@Subscribe
public void onFirstEvent(FirstEvent event) {
    ...
    bus.post(new SecondEvent(...));
}
```

And in my other class, where I handle `SecondEvent`, I use a subscribe method in the same way. The problem is, the method that subscribes to `SecondEvent`is called even before `onFirstEvent()` is called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onFirstEvent(Event event) {
    if (event instanceof FirstEvent) {
        ...
        bus.post(new SecondEvent(...));
    } else if (event instanceof SecondEvent) {
        // process
    }

}
```

you can test like this

Comment: How will this solve the problem? You mean I remove the SecondEVent subscriber method, and handle it within onFirstEvent itself?